# Connecting MYSQL DB with Android application

Tags: android, mysql, database

Guys my main goal is to connect this db with my android app but for some reason ive been getting an error in connection and cannot figure it out. So im resulting to stackoverflow to sort this out for me

given below is the SC of my main activity

```
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    db_connect db_connect;
    ImageButton mood;
    ImageButton statistic;
    double emotion;
    Button btnEmotion;
    ProgressBar pbbar;








    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db_connect = new db_connect();
        btnEmotion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnEmotion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DoCheck doCheck = new DoCheck();
                doCheck.execute("");

            }
        });

        mood = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        statistic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    }


    public class DoCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (isSuccess) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        // Connection With SQL Server

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            try {
                Connection con = db_connect.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error:505 in connecting with the Database";

                } else {

                    //SQL Select Query
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM emotiontable WHERE emotions=' " +emotion;
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


                    //Emotion Calculation

                    if (emotion <= 0.98755) {

                        z = "The child is Happy";
                        isSuccess = true;

                    } else if (emotion <= 0.00300731952) {
                        z = "The Child is Anger";
                        isSuccess = true;


                    } else if (emotion <= 5.14648448) {
                        z = "The Child is Contempt";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else if (emotion <= 9.180124) {
                        z = "The Child is Disgusted";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else if (emotion <= 0.0001912825) {
                        z = "The Child is fear";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else if (emotion <= 0.0009861537) {
                        z = "The Child is Nutral";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else if (emotion <= 1.889955) {
                        z = "The Child is sad";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else if (emotion <= 0.008229999) {
                        z = "The Child is Surprised";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = "No Emotion Data Found";
            }

            return z;
        }
    }
}

      /*  public void emotionView(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Emotion.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        public void stats(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Statistics.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
    }*/
```

Comment: `ive been getting an error in connection` where is the error and it's stacktrace?

Comment: @vladMatvienko . No its just Error 505. Letting me know i cant connect to the db

Comment: Why is it 505? why did you call it 505? What is a `db_connect` class? what does `db_connect.CONN()` do?

Comment: @VladMatvienko 505 was created on my end as a reference for me. db_connect is the class i created to connect my db to the localhost. .conn is the connection i require to be done

Comment: then you have some error in your class. About which localhost you are talking? `http://localhost`? And you connect to the localhost from your Android device?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes sir, im actually stuck trying to figure that error. The local db is hosted using mamp to test it

Comment: `local db is hosted` where is it hosted? `localhost` points to **myself**. So for the Android phone it will point to Android phone. If your `local db` is hosted not on the phone, then you won't be able to connect to it using `localhost`